# How to create object of another javascript class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I want to create an object of `ProfileComparator` in another `index.js` file but I am getting an error.

### strategy.js

```
var cosineUtils = require("./jscosine");

var ProfileComparator = function(algo, x, y, threshold) {
  this.algo = algo;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.threshold = threshold;
};

ProfileComparator.prototype.findMatches = function() {
  return this.algo(this.x, this.y, this.threshold);
};

var cosineAlgoStrategy = function(x, y, threshold) {
  var similarityCount = cosineUtils.cosineSimilarity(x, y);

  if (similarityCount >= threshold) {
    return y;
  }

  console.log("------------------------------------");
  console.log("cosine");
  console.log("------------------------------------");
};

var pearsonAlgoStrategy = function(x, y, threshold) {
  console.log("------------------------------------");
  console.log(threshold);
  console.log("------------------------------------");
};
```

I am able to create object of `ProfileComparator` in `strategy.js` not in other javascript file like below

```
var cosineAlgo = new ProfileComparator(cosineAlgoStrategy, "x", "y", 0.9);
return cosineAlgo.findMatches();
```

index.js

I am trying to do same in `index.js` but I am getting an error here:

```
var strategyUtils = require("./strategy");

function computeSimilarity(x, user) {
  var cosineAlgo = new ProfileComparator(cosineAlgoStrategy, x, y, 0.9);
  return cosineAlgo.findMatches();
}
```

StackTrace:

```
ReferenceError: ProfileComparator is not defined
    at computeSimilarity (/user_code/index.js:187:24)
    at /user_code/index.js:232:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it ?

Comment: I don't see any exports

Comment: You have not exported `ProfileComparator` from `strategy.js` file.

Comment: Use 'export' befor func name. Then it will accessible outside of local file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with your **exported class and algorithms** that you might wanna use in your Comparator:

```
const ProfileComparator = function(algo, x, y, threshold) {
  this.algo = algo
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.threshold = threshold
}

ProfileComparator.prototype.findMatches = function() {
  return this.algo(this.x, this.y, this.threshold)
}

const cosineAlgoStrategy = function(x, y, threshold) {
  var similarityCount = cosineUtils.cosineSimilarity(x, y)

  if (similarityCount >= threshold) {
    return y
  }

  console.log('------------------------------------')
  console.log('cosine')
  console.log('------------------------------------')
}

const pearsonAlgoStrategy = function(x, y, threshold) {
  console.log('------------------------------------')
  console.log(threshold)
  console.log('------------------------------------')
}

module.exports = { ProfileComparator, cosineAlgoStrategy, pearsonAlgoStrategy }
```

This would be your new **index.js** file where you import all you needed modules:

```
const { ProfileComparator, cosineAlgoStrategy, pearsonAlgoStrategy } = require("./strategy");

function computeSimilarity(x, user) {
    var cosineAlgo = new ProfileComparator(cosineAlgoStrategy, x, y, 0.9);
    return cosineAlgo.findMatches();
}
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: ProfileComparator is not a constructor
    at computeSimilarity (/user_code/index.js:191:20)
    at /user_code/index.js:236:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)`

Comment: @Williams I corrected my code. I was just typing, what I had on my mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it worked. I didn't know that we can export multiple too using this syntax

Comment: @Williams you are welcome. Sure you can use this 'trick', creating an export object, which you then destruct on the import side to access the functionalities more easily.

Comment: If I add var instead of const here `const { ProfileComparator, cosineAlgoStrategy, pearsonAlgoStrategy } = require("./strategy");` then it won't work ?

Comment: const and var are just to different variable declaration, yes it will work. But there's a style guide line to use constant as an import, because it should be immutable.

Comment: ah gotcha. ..:) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to export your `ProfileComparator` comparator function from `strategy.js` file like this

```
module.exports = ProfileComparator
```

And in your index.js, require it like this

```
var ProfileComparator = require("./strategy");
```

Comment: I am getting this now `ReferenceError: cosineAlgoStrategy is not defined
    at computeSimilarity (/user_code/index.js:187:42)
    at /user_code/index.js:232:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)` here `var cosineAlgo = new ProfileComparator(cosineAlgoStrategy, x, y, 0.9);`

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix

You need to export the ProfileComparator! 
Add: `module.exports = ProfileComparator;` to the end of the strategy.js file! 
Now you can require it in other files with something like this:
`var ProfileComparator = require('path/to/the/module');`.
 Dont forget to checkout this: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

#### Explanation of the error

The error occurred because you tried to create a new instance of the ProfileComparator without it beeing in scope!

Comment: I am getting this now `ReferenceError: cosineAlgoStrategy is not defined at computeSimilarity (/user_code/index.js:187:42) at /user_code/index.js:232:16 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)` here `var cosineAlgo = new ProfileComparator(cosineAlgoStrategy, x, y, 0.9);`

Comment: Right, this variable is not in scope!

Comment: I will add the solution to my answer later!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var ProfileComparator = function(algo, x, y, threshold) {
  this.algo = algo;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.threshold = threshold;
};
```

To

```
export const ProfileComparator = function(algo, x, y, threshold) {
  this.algo = algo;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.threshold = threshold;
};
```

Import as

```
Import { ProfileComparator } from '<file location>'
```

Comment: not natively working in nodejs, since `export/import` isn't standardized, yet.